# JQuery checkbox detected as on when unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox and I am using JQuery to submit the values so that I can pick them up on the next page.

However, my checkbox always shows an 'on' even though it is unchecked.

How can I detect the right value whilst passing the array to the next page?
My JQuery code:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
                    var myData = [];
                    var rows = $('#customFields').find('tr');
                    rows.find('td input').each(function() {
                        myData.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    alert(myData);
                    $('#invoiceitems').val(myData);
                    $('#form1').submit();
                });
```

Thanks

Comment: so you only want to pass checked values?

Comment: Actually.. I need to get all the value as there are textboxes in that table.

Comment: check simplest way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
rows.find('td input').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checkbox')){
        myData.push(this.checked);
    }else{
        myData.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```